# 2 dimensional array to object in C# linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, linq

I have a class

```
public class SomeClass {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Age{get;set;}
        }
```

I have an array declared

```
string[,] testArray = { { "Vignesh", "25" },{"Raja","20"} };
```

I tried to convert the `testArray` to object of `SomeClass[]` using linq to sql
But `testArray.Select(` is not coming. It says `String[*,*] does not contain a definition for Select`

```
var result = linqArray.Cast<string>().Select(x => x).ToArray();
            linqArray.Cast<string>()
 .Select(x => new SomeClass { Name =x, Age = x })
 .ToArray();
```

When I try this it is result is like shown below

[image]

I even tried type casting, which didnt work

```
SomeClass[] list = (SomeClass[])linqArray;
```

Comment: I think this needs some more clarity, I'm pretty sure the the second c# snippet isn't proper c#

Comment: `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: Why do you use a mutli-dimentsional array in the first place?

Comment: Yes @Sinatr it is there

Comment: @vignesh Why not use Dictionary<string,int>?
I think it suits you for your task.

Comment: @netwer: Often these questions are a cutdown version of the full code. In this case that might work but in reality I would guess that `SomeClass` probably has more properties on it. The nature of `SomeClass` is not important to the question, just the fact that it is in a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 3):

It's because multidimensional arrays are not `IEnumerable<T>`.First you need to turn your array into `IEnumerable<T>` using `Cast` or `OfType` method, then you can use [`Batch`](https://morelinq.googlecode.com/hg/docs/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Batch__1.htm) method:

```
array.Cast<string>()
 .Batch(2)
 .Select(x => new SomeClass { Name = x.First(), Age = x.Last()) })
 .ToArray();
```

Note you need to add a reference to [`MoreLINQ`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library to use `Batch` method.